# Forward .NET emails to corresponding .COM email accounts

Tags: redirects, email, mx, email-accounts

Domain.**NET** is hosted at Network Solutions (no comments, please; not my choice) and domain.**COM** is hosted at Blue Host (same). Email accounts at **.NET** have been used for years; email accounts at **.COM** have recently been set up and users were instructed to *add* **.COM** email accounts to email clients, while retaining **.NET** accounts, so they should be receiving emails both **.NET** and **.COM** accounts in their email clients across all devices.

Ideally, we would do a global forward of **.NET** email to corresponding **.COM** and all would be right in the world.  But. There's always a but ... that doesn't seem to be an option or I can find the *how* for that solution.

Network Solutions account doesn't have either cPanel or Plesk access (basic hosting account) and support is, simply, useless.  I *could* change everyone's passwords and then access NS webmail for each individual to do the forwards. Every user has multiple devices which will throw errors the second I change the passwords.  (And these people are not ever all available at the same time for an email sync party.)

Client desires (reasonably):

1. No email downtime
2. No user intervention for the forwards
3. No loss of data

Blue Host will let me do an addon domain, and I could gain control by doing that. And that may be my only option.  I have a concern, however, if any of the **.NET** email accounts were set to leave emails on the server, this may be a loss of historical data.

I do understand that I can redirect NS email to BH by adding an A Mail record with the proper IP and point the MX record to **.COM**, but ... then what?  How does Blue Host know what to do with the mail?  It doesn't seem to resolve my problem.

So ... I'm either being very, very blonde or completely overthinking this (I've spent hours looking for a workaround to NS's lack of access).  One thing I know:  I can't possibly be the first person to ever need to do something like this.  Yet I can't seem to find an answer.

I've spent hours on these boards the past few years and always find great solutions.  I am confident many of you are far more knowledgeable than I -- if you can help, but I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: I do not work in e-mail much anymore, but I am thinking that you can simply add the .net version of the domain name to your e-mail server and change the A record to point to the BlueHost server. It the e-mail server is something like Postfix you should be able to define where the user@example.com e-mails are delivered to. Unfortunately, I do not remember how at just this moment. That is the way I would go.

Comment: Thank you, @closetnoc.  After a couple of days of debating, we went with changing everyone's .NET passwords and manually forwarding using NS Webmail. We turned the con -- everyone's devices throwing "enter network password" errors when we changed the p'words -- into a pro:  When the devices threw the errors (because they didn't read the instructional email we sent), they came back asking for the resolution, and we deleted the .NET accounts from their devices.